# intuition for singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

SVD says, for $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, there exist orthogonal matrices $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and diagonal matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with positive entries such that $M = U \Sigma V^T$.

I can see that intuitively SVD tells us every linear transformation on real vector spaces can be realized as a rotation ($V^T = V^{-1}$), followed by scaling ($\Sigma$), and then another rotation ($U$).

From most of the sources I've seen, I see the theorem being presented as $M = U \Sigma V^T$ instead of $M = U \Sigma V^{-1}$. Personally, inverse of a matrix is easier to understand, compared to transpose (I don't have a good intuition for transpose, except a vague idea that it is an operation that "preserves geometry").

My main question is, is there any reason that the theorem is most commonly presented in terms of transpose instead of inverse?

Comment: Since $V$ is orthogonal, $V^{-1} = V^T$.

Comment: Thanks - I know that, but I'm curious to know why we chose to use transpose in the theorem if using inverse might have a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: The dyadic expansion of $M$ falls out more naturally with $V^T$ rather than $V^{-1}$.

Comment: $V^T$ is conceptually and technically simpler (columns become lines, that's all)...